# createMediaElementSource not working in android

Tags: android, web-audio-api

I want to play an audio file, and at the same time, analyze the file

The following code runs on chrome desktop

But in chrome android (current version 119) it does not start playing

```
    <html>
<style>
button {
    font-size: 500%;
}
</style>
<script>
function start() {
  var ctx = new AudioContext();
  console.log(ctx);
  
  var el = document.getElementById("audio");  
  console.log(el);
  
  var source = ctx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
  source.connect(ctx.destination);
  el.play();
}
</script>
<body>
<br/>
<audio id="audio" src="audio.mp3" controls preload="auto" crossOrigin="anonymous"></audio>
<br/>
<button type="button" onclick="start()">Click Me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```